# Good practices for handling form submission on codeigniter/php website

Tags: ajax, forms, codeigniter, controller, form-submit

I'm building a website with codeigniter and I'm creating a form for user submission.

I'm thinking about having the form submit with an javascript/AJAX call to a special controller intended just to handle form submissions and redirecting the user to an appropriate page based off the response from that controller.

Is this a good idea? I imagine my site will have lots of forms so I'm thinking a special controller just to handle their submission is a good idea. But obviously I will need to prevent users from ever directly accessing any of the methods in this controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your form works **without** javascript, and then you can use `$this->input->is_ajax_request()` to check if the form is being submitted with ajax, and do something different with your output.

This avoids the need for "ajax only" controllers, methods, and URLs, and keeps all your form processing logic together in one place. If it's *not* an ajax request, no one will ever be able to see the output so you don't need to worry.

Comment: Thanks @Wesley Murch, that was helpful. I'm using that test to keep my form presentation logic and regular view-logic in the same controller.